# Get document on some condition in elastic search java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

As I know we can parse document in elastic search, And when we search for a keyword, It will return the document using this code of java API:-

```
  org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse searchHits =  node.client()
            .prepareSearch()
            .setIndices("indices")
            .setQuery(qb)
            .setFrom(0).setSize(1000)
            .addHighlightedField("file.filename")
            .addHighlightedField("content")
            .addHighlightedField("meta.title")
            .setHighlighterPreTags("<span class='badge badge-info'>")
            .setHighlighterPostTags("</span>")
            .addFields("*", "_source")
            .execute().actionGet();
```

Now my question is, suppose some documents have string like these:-

```
Jun 2010 to Sep 2011                First Document          
Jun 2009 to Aug 2011                Second Document             
Nov 2011 – Sep 2012                 Third Document   
Nov  2012- Sep 2013                 Forth Document   
Nov 2013 – Current                  First Document   
June 2014 – Feb 2015                Third Document   
Jan 2013 – Jan 2014                 Second Document   
July 2008 – Oct 2012                First Document   
May 2007 – Current                  Forth Document
```

Now i want those documents who comes between these conditions:-

```
1 to 12 months
13-24 months
26-48 months
```

How i can do this?

Comment: Now i am able to read document content when i am indexing it. Is there any way or can we use regular expression by which we can get 'Jun 2010 to Sep 2011' string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When indexing documents in this form, Elasticsearch will not be able to parse those strings as dates correctly. In case you transformed those strings to [correctly formatted timestamps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html), the only way you could perform the query you propose is to index those documents in this format

```
{
  "start": "2010-09",
  "end": "2011-10",
  // rest of the document
}
```

and subsequently run a [script-filtered](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html) query over them, compiling a script that calculates the difference between those two dates with one of the scripting languages Elasticsearch provides. Bear in mind that script filtering and scoring is always much slower than a simple index lookup.

A much faster and cleaner way to do this is to index the duration of the period alongside the start and end dates, like so

```
{
  "start": "2010-09",
  "end": "2011-10",
  "duration": 13
  // the rest of the document
}
```

If you index your documents in this form, you can simply perform a filtered query on the duration field:

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "and":[
               {
                  "range":{
                     "duration":{
                        "gte":1
                     }
                  }
               },
               {
                  "range":{
                     "duration":{
                        "lte":12
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. i am also thinking same. Thats why i ask, How we can parse ''Jun 2010 to Sep 2011'' or 'Jun 2010 - Sep 2011' string from content string in java using regular expression.

Comment: If the months have standard 3-letter names, you can use the Joda time library to parse the dates very easily (see http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). Otherwise. I'd suggest to simply split the date on space and write a simple switch/case to transform the months into numbers.

Comment: I am trying to split the date on space, But in sample resumes, Some dates have 2 or 3 spaces. So that's fail in that time. And I dont have any experience in JODA library.