# Next digit after a word using index position in java

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this question:

[Get document on some condition in elastic search java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972581/get-document-on-some-condition-in-elastic-search-java-api)

My logic is first we get all the position of months which is in string, After that i extract next word which is a 4 digit or 2 digit year, Then calculate difference using this.

For getting months position i am using this piece of code:-

```
       String[] threeMonthArray=new String[]{" Jan "," Feb "," Mar "," Apr "," May "," June "," July "," Aug "," Sep "," Oct "," Nov "," Dec "};
        String[] completeMonthArray=new String[]{"January","Feburary","March","April","May","June","July","Augest","September","October","November","December"};
       List indexArray=new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<threeMonthArray.length;i++){
            int index = parsedContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(threeMonthArray[i].toLowerCase());
            while (index >= 0) {
                System.out.println(threeMonthArray[i]+" : "+index+"------");
                indexArray.add(index);
                index = parsedContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(threeMonthArray[i].toLowerCase(), index + 1);
            }
            // System.out.println(threeMonthArray[i]+" : "+parsedContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(threeMonthArray[i].toLowerCase())+"------");
        }
       Collections.sort(indexArray);
        System.out.println(   indexArray);
```

And it's showing this output:-

```
 [2873, 2884, 3086, 3098, 4303, 4315, 6251, 6262, 8130, 8142, 15700, 15711]
```

I am getting correct position. My problem is how i can get next word which  must be a digit.

```
Jun 2010 to Sep 2011                First Document          
Jun 2009 to Aug 2011                Second Document             
Nov 2011 – Sep 2012                 Third Document   
Nov  2012- Sep 2013                 Forth Document
```

Comment: What is `parsedContent` in `parsedContent.toLowerCase()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find the next number starting at the position of your last found month:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(parsedContent);
if (m.find(index)) {
    String year = m.group();
}
```

Comment: Wow. Working. Thanks. I will post original question solution if i get.